# Number Theory Problem That I don't Know Has a Solution

Tags: number-theory

Let $x$ and $n$ be positive integers. For what values $x$ and $n$ satisfy $x^2+615=2^{2n}$? Express as an ordered pair $(x,n)$.

Comment: Goodness, have you even tried to look for *examples* yourself first?  Just TRY SOMETHING and tell us what you found before asking others for help. (If $n$ is really meant to be there with the first power then you are trying to solve a congruence mod 4.)

Comment: The problem typed out wrong, srry

Comment: Ok, i forgot to bracket the exponent if you couldn't tell... chill :)

Comment: No, I couldn't tell earlier.  People post all kinds of questions here, some of which are dead easy and I figured this was yet another one like those.  Now I see your corrected question has some meat to it.  Still, you should do some numerical testing yourself first to check for any low-hanging solutions (say, with $1 \leq n \leq 50$) and report what you find as part of asking your question.  Also, what is the background for this: tell us where this question is coming from and if you have ever seen how to solve anything like this before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$615=2^{2n}-x^2=(2^n-x)(2^n+x)$$

Since $615=3 \cdot 5\cdot 41$ and $2^n+x>2^n-x$ there are few possible solutions:

$$2^n+x= 615 \\
2^n-x=1$$
or
$$2^n+x=205  \\
2^n-x=3$$
or
$$2^n+x= 123 \\
2^n-x=5$$
or
$$2^n+x= 41 \\
2^n-x=15$$

Now, simply solve each system, and check if $n$ is an integer. Note that this happens exactly when the sum on the RHS is a power of 2, which is only the case for $123+5=128$.

Comment: ok, I get it! At first, I combined the $2^2n$ into $4^n$ and didn't get much. Turns out, it was meant to be used for difference of squares. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$(2^n-x^2)(2^n-x^2)=615=3\cdot5\cdot 41$. Only

$2^n-x^2 = 5$ and $2^n+x^2 = 123$ equations gives solution and we find $(x,n)=(59,6)$

Answer (score 1):

One answer is  $ 59^2+615 = 2^{2*6}$ so the pair is $(59, 6)$ you can find this by trying numbers, (I used a script).

$$
x^2+615=2^{2n} = 4^n
$$
$$
log_4{(x^2+615)}=n
$$

You need to try different x values until you get an integer answer

Comment: I'm not sure such brute force calculation will help charaterize _all_ such number pairs.

Comment: since OP hasn't shown any effort in solving this I just wanted to give him one solution so he can use that to test his method. But since he didn't show us anything he tried I am not going to solve his homework quite yet.

Comment: I agree about that, but I don't think it should be posted as an _answer_ then; it's more of a comment.